# Are there any default background images you can choose from in the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, ipad

When I do a UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal I want to see the bg image from the multitasking menu or from when you drag a outside of a page in Safari. Is this something Apple supply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of, yes. Take a look at these `UIColor` methods:

```
+ groupTableViewBackgroundColor
+ viewFlipsideBackgroundColor
+ scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor
+ underPageBackgroundColor
```

You can use those to set background "colours" which are actually pattern image colours. Other than those there is nothing else supplied (as far as I know anyway).

For example (thanks @JonRamvi):

```
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
```

Comment: Thanks! Code example for others: window.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

Answer (score 0):

The cross hatch background colour is available as scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor, a class method on UIColor. If you want to see that during a modal transition I think you should set the backgroundColor of the apps window in the app delegate to this colour